# error: ambiguous overload for 'operator/'

Tags: python, c, numpy, math, overloading

I am new to c, and the following is giving me some grief:

```
int i,j,ll,k;
double ddim,ddip,ddjm,ddjp,ddlm,ddlp;
for(i=1; i<(mx-1); i++){
for(j=1; j<(my-1); j++){
 for(ll=1; ll<(mz-1); ll++){

 ddim=0.5*k
 ddip=0.5*k
 ddjm=0.5*k
 ddjp=0.5*k
 ddlm=0.5*k
 ddlp=0.5*k

  Wijl(i,j,ll) =  ((1.0/h_x)*(ddip) \
     ((1.0/h_x)*(ddim))   \
     ((1.0/h_y)*(ddjp))   \
     ((1.0/h_y)*(ddjm))   \
     ((1.0/h_z)*(ddlp))   \
     ((1.0/h_z)*(ddlm)) ; 
          }
     }
}
```

I then compile this with gcc using python and scipy, passing it everything that is not initialized, but I know the problem is in the 1.0/h_x part of the code. If I compile basic c statements using python/gcc it works, so I am not having a python/gcc issue.

The error I am getting is: "error: ambiguous overload for 'operator/' in '1.0e+0 / h_x'

It seems like it is trying to do assignment overloading, and all I want to do is division!

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Thanks,

Tyler

Comment: Brilliantly obfuscated code, was that intentional? ;-)

Comment: Could you include more of the code?  For example, where is h_x declared?

Comment: Why are you using a C++ compiler?

Comment: Lol yeah....I did not write this, teammate did, just trying to understand it!

Comment: @tylerthe miler:  I rolled back the deletion of code, because the question makes absolutely no sense with just two closing braces for code.  I'd rather not see meaningless questions hanging around SO.  If there's some reason you don't want the code showing, flag this for moderator attention.

Comment: Oh sorry! I'm not sure how the edit ended up like that.....must have failed at my copy/paste...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's trying to say that it's not clear what type h_x is, so it doesn't know which of the overloaded / operators to use (double/int, double/double, etc). You could try casting it (h_x) to int or double to tell it what version to use.

Comment: That is exactly what the problem is! How do I resolve it?? Is it saying that h_x isn't a double/int/ect??

Comment: I presume you pass h_x from python? I'm not sure about how you would do this, but shouldn't the C code be inside a function that you call from python, having h_x as parameter (with the type set). I didn't see h_x declared anywhere, so I don't know (like the compiler) what type it should be. In the worst case scenario you should be able to cast it like i suggested in the (edited) answer.

Comment: Found this regarding compiling a module of C code to be used in python, maybe it will help: http://kortis.to/radix/python_ext/ I see that there they do `!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i", &input)` to transform the input argument from python object to int (input is type int, args is type PythonObject), maybe you need seomthing similar.

Comment: So I have it running (or at least that assignment isn't throwing an error and it's compiling)! I am just getting a different python-related error now...

If I put a fprint statement in the loop it prints, so it seems like the code is working, but here is how I compile it using pytho/ scipy.

code = """ everything in my original post """

weave.inline(code,['Wijl','q','diff','mx','my','mz','h_x','h_y','h_z'],type_converters=converters.blitz,compiler='gcc')  

SystemError: NULL result without error in PyObject_Call

Comment: Thanks for the help! It turned out to be something completely unrelated to any of that, but they did need to be doubles.

Answer (score 0):

If `h_x` is `float` then dividing `1.0` (by default `double`) by it leaves C wondering whether to do the operation in float or double math.

If you want to do it in floats, change `1.0` to `1.0f`; if double, either declare or cast your `h_x` to `double`.

If `h_x` is `int` (that's what I'm afraid of) you'd probably do well to assign your `h_?`'s to three corresponding float or double temp variables outside the loop, to save the compiler from (possibly) doing lots of unnecessary int-to-float conversions. As a side effect, this will make your type ambiguity go away.

---

You could also simplify the code a bit by getting rid of those `1.0`'s: Instead of multiplying by the reciprocal, you could simply divide those expressions by `h_whatever`. Especially as the right half of each of those lines is already doing something similar.

Comment: C does not "wonder" in mixed-type arithmetical operations. The language specification has precise and explicit rules for what to do in cases like that.

Comment: You're right. If the type of h_x was `float` or `double` there shouldn't be any ambiguity about the intended type of the operation. Maybe the issue is being muddled by the linkage from Python.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest that you carefully peal off all of the utterly redundant parentheses and examine carefully what is left.

For example, this snippet:

```
((1.0/h_x)*(ddim)*((q(i,j,ll) - q(i-1,j,ll)))/h_x)
```

boils down to:

```
ddim * (q(i,j,ll) - q(i-1,j,ll)) / h_x / h_x
```

Note that the original separation of the two occurrences of `/ h_x` makes one wonder what the original intention was.